# Fitnesse and ServiceFixture: variables not recognized

Tags: fitnesse

I'm trying to use the [ServiceFixture](http://servicefixture.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) with Fitnesse. The problem I have is that I can't use the variable that I define with the key row:

```
|key|foobar|
|check|response != null|true|
|check|response.customerId|
```

In this example I define foobar. I should be able to use this in a next test with ${foobar.response.customerId}. However I get an error, undefined variable: foobar.response.customerID in Fitnesse. Also built-in variables/functions like ${random.string} are not recognized.

We are using Fitnesse-20111025

Any help/hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question: escaping the variables is enough:

!-${foobar.response.customerId}-!

does the trick for me